# Laravel if use wherebetwheen, Data not show all

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> If i use whereBetween then all data is not shown like [image1] but if not use, data show all. I want use whereBetween and data can show all like [image2]

MyController

```
$tanggal= $request->reservation;
              $date= explode('-', $tanggal);
              $start=Carbon::parse($date[0])->format('Y-m-d') ;
              $end=Carbon::parse($date[1])->format('Y-m-d') ;

              
                $pemakaian   = DB::table('tb_alat')
                              ->leftJoin('tb_bbms','tb_alat.id_alat','=','tb_bbms.id_alat')
                              ->select('tb_alat.id_alat','tb_alat.nama_alat',DB::raw('SUM(tb_bbms.bbm) as bbm'),DB::raw('SUM(tb_bbms.tarif) as tarif'),DB::raw('SUM(tb_bbms.jam_operasi) as jam'))
                              ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
                              ->groupBy('tb_alat.id_alat')
                              ->get();

              
                               return view('page.laporanpdf.sumarypdf', compact('pemakaian', 'start','end'));
```

View Blade

```
<table width="100%" class="table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Nama Alat</th>
            <th>Jam Operasi</th>
            <th>Jumlah Pemakaian (Liter)</th>
            <th>Rata-Rata (Liter)</th>
            <th>Biaya</th>
            
                    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php $no = 1; @endphp
       @foreach($pemakaian as $list)
          
            <tr>
              <td>{{$no++}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->nama_alat}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->jam}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->bbm}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->bbm}}</td>
              <td>{{format_uang($list->tarif)}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Total</td>
            
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRMtk.jpg)

No  Nama Alat   Jam Operasi     Jumlah Pemakaian (Liter)    Rata-Rata (Liter)   Biaya

1   FD  323988  79  79  Rp. 869.000

2   RG  0   80  80  Rp. 624.000

3   RG  1   87  87  Rp. 678.600

4   GENSET  -7527   89  89  Rp. 0

Total

and i want data show all
like here

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2upe.jpg)

Comment: Try somthing like  this whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), array($start, $end))->get(); , or you can also use Carbon

Comment: here whereBetween takes all the data created between your given timeframe. what's not working expectedly??

Answer (score 0):

Are u converting request $start & $end to date field?

if no.

You should convert it to date field.

**Sample Code**

```
 $start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start));
 $end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end));
```

Hope this will be useful.